# read the file and prduce sorted dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Create a file with contents:

```
Mary,Jane : 5.8 Mary,Doe : 6.0 John,Doe : 6.3 John,Muller : 5.6 Mary,Muller : 6.5
```

Read this file and create a dictionary with keys of the type tuple and values of the type float  i.e., an item of the dictionary should look like this:

```
(‘Mary’,’Jane’) : 5.8
```

Convert this dictionary into a list of tuples. Sort them in decreasing order and print them.

my code is:

```
f = open('sam.txt', 'r')
answer = {}
tuple(answer.keys())
for i in answer:
    print tuple(answer.keys())  
for line in f:

    k, v = ((line.strip()).split(':'))
    answer[((k.strip()))] = float(v.strip())
print answer    
c = answer.items()
d = sorted(c)
print tuple(reversed(sorted(c)))
f.close()
```

Here I am getting keys of dictionary as string not tuple as prescribed please tell me my mistake and please do some fine tunes to my regarding problem.

Comment: Why are you performing operations on the answer dictionary when it is clearly empty?

Comment: You're not using `d` and therefore you sort twice. By the way instead of `reversed(sorted(c))` you can do `sorted(c, reverse=True)`.

Comment: i am asked to use reversed() function so I try like that

Answer (score 0):

You should also *split* the keys on comma `','` and not only *strip*:

```
answer[tuple(k.strip().split(','))] = float(v.strip())
```

On a side note, you don't need that initial dict stunt code:

```
answer = {}
with open('sam.txt') as f: # open with context manager does auto close
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.strip().split(':')
        answer[tuple(k.strip().split(','))] = float(v.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Its much easier if you have your data in new lines like this:

```
Mary,Jane : 5.8 
Mary,Doe : 6.0 
John,Doe : 6.3 
John,Muller : 5.6 
Mary,Muller : 6.5
```

and then the code would be :

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
answer = {}
for line in f:
    k, v = ((line.strip()).split(':'))
    key1, key2 = k.split(',')
    answer[(key1, key2)] = float(v.strip())

print answer
c = answer.items()
d = sorted(c)
print tuple(reversed(sorted(c)))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did answer like this may i know is there any further upgrade needed to it to make it more efficient

```
f = open('sam.txt')
answer = {tuple(x.split(':')[0].strip().split(',')): float(x.split('[1].strip()) for x in f}
print "\ndictionary taken from file is:\n"
print answer    
c = answer.items()
d = sorted(c)
print "\nafter sorted and converted into tuples the output is:\n"
print tuple(reversed(sorted(c)))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Built-in functions are often useful, but sometimes all you need is a simple regular expression:

```
# Generate file
txt = "Mary,Jane : 5.8 Mary,Doe : 6.0 John,Doe : 6.3 John,Muller : 5.6 Mary,Muller : 6.5"
with open("out.txt","w+") as FILE: FILE.write(txt)

# Read file and grab content
content= [ re.findall(r"([A-Za-z]+),([A-Za-z]+)\s:\s([0-9]\.[0-9])",line) for line in tuple(open("out.txt","r")) ]

# Make dictionary
dct = {(k1,k2):float(v) for (k1,k2,v) in reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, content)}
print(dct)
```